# Grabbing entire url as variable with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

This is an image rotator that I'm trying to be able to manage completely through the url to avoid having to setup a user login system. With this system, the urls of the images to be added and removed from the list are passed through the url as a variable. When I type out the entire url: `http://www.url.com/index.php?add=http://www.url2.com/images/image.png` it works fine. When I try to do it with an htaccess file, `http://www.url.com/add=http://www.url2.com/images/image.png`, I get a 403.

Applicable .htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^add\=(.*)/? index.php?add=$1 [QSA]
```

This htaccess line works as long as I'm not trying to submit an entire url. Any ideas? If this isn't enough information just let me know.

-- Edit --

Added more information about the url that I'm trying to retreive

Comment: There is no code here for causing 403

Comment: I added a bit more about the url. I don't understand why using the htaccess file on this particular setup causes the 403, but it most definitely does.

Comment: I am getting a 403 too here, even without the htaccess, a colon in the url causes a 403.

Comment: That's odd, I'm not having that issue if I manually type everything out.

Comment: The reason is because it's not a valid URL to begin with. You can't have two colons in the path. You can have them in the query string though but not in the path. `http://localhost/add=http://localhost/` is an invalid URL. You can, however put a `?` in front so it accepts the colon. Or simply omit the scheme.

Comment: put the ? where exactly?

Comment: Like so: `http://localhost/?add=http://localhost/`
or if you wanna get fancy without using the query string, you can use a slash instead and attempt to rebuild the URL from PHP:
`http://localhost/add=http///localhost/`

Comment: Yeah, the question mark did the trick and is the easiest fix so it will be the answer! Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... google managed to catch such malformed URLs as `http://www.google.com/search=http://` and send it to their custom 404 page. So it looks like it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from Ultimater and the solution:

**The reason is because it's not a valid URL to begin with. You can't have two colons in the path. You can have them in the query string though but not in the path. `http://localhost/add=http://localhost/` is an invalid URL. You can, however put a `?` in front so it accepts the colon. Or simply omit the scheme. – Ultimater**

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /add=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?add=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That works perfectly in my testing. Can you provide details what you tried and what error you got? DO you have other rules also?